# Find a string within a range and set cell address as new range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search for a string within a sheet and return the cell address so that I can use that address to populate adjacent cells with info. My problem is with setting "Daycell" as the cell reference, can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
 Private Sub Enter_Click()
    Dim FindWor As Range
    Dim Findrng As String
    Dim FindRowNumber As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim frq As String
    Dim wkday As String
    Dim nwday As String
    Dim Mnth As String
    Dim Daycell As Range
    Dim entryno As String
    Dim Dayno As String

    frq = Me.No1

    'Date from userform
    Findrng = Me.Date1
    'Reoccuring interval from userform
    If Not Me.Freq1 = "No" Then

        Do While i < Me.No1
            'This part adds the title and the detail to a data sheet with 3 possible entries per day
            With Worksheets("Data").Range("$A:$A")
                Set FindWor = .Find(What:=CDate(Findrng))
                FindRowNumber = FindWor.Row

                'Checks for the 1st empty row and populates
                If .Cells(FindRowNumber, 2) = "" Then
                    .Cells(FindRowNumber, 2).Value = Me.Event1
                    .Cells(FindRowNumber, 3).Value = Me.Details1
                    entryno = 1
                ElseIf .Cells(FindRowNumber, 4) = "" Then
                    .Cells(FindRowNumber, 4).Value = Me.Event1
                    .Cells(FindRowNumber, 5).Value = Me.Details1
                    entryno = 2
                ElseIf .Cells(FindRowNumber, 6) = "" Then
                    .Cells(FindRowNumber, 6).Value = Me.Event1
                    .Cells(FindRowNumber, 7).Value = Me.Details1
                    entryno = 3
                End If

                'This part is to enter the detail part into the cell within the correct monthly tab as a comment
                Mnth = (Month((CDate(Findrng))))
                Mnth = MonthName(Mnth, True)
                With Worksheets(Mnth).Range("$A:$Z")
                    Dayno = Day(CDate(Findrng))
                    Set Daycell = .Find(What:=Dayno, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                    'This is where I think my issue is as I want the comment to be in the cell below the day number (the days are displayed as day number only
                    .Cell(Daycell).Offset (1)

                    'I am not sure if this will work, I want the comment to go into the corresponding cell as stated by the entryno that is created above
                    If .Cells(Daycell) = "" Then
                        Range(Daycell).NoteText Text:=Me.Details1.Value
                        Else: .Cell(Daycell).Offset (entryno)
                    End If

                End With

                'this part then loops based upon the frq and the no1 from the userform
                If Me.Freq1 = "Daily" Then
                    Findrng = Findrng + 1

                ElseIf Me.Freq1 = "Weekly" Then
                    Findrng = Findrng + 7

                ElseIf Me.Freq1 = "Bi-Weekly" Then
                    Findrng = Findrng + 14

                    'the parts below check for the correct working day
                ElseIf Me.Freq1 = "Monthly" Then
                    wkday = Format(CDate(DateAdd("M", 1, (CDate(Findrng)) + 1)), "MM/DD/YYYY")
                    bday = DateAdd("D", -1, ((Format(wkday, "DD/MM/YYYY"))))
                    nwday = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(wkday, -1))
                    Findrng = bday

                ElseIf Me.Freq1 = "Quaterly" Then
                    wkday = CDate(Format(DateAdd("M", 3, (CDate(Findrng))) + 1, "MM/DD/YYYY"))
                    bday = DateAdd("D", -1, ((Format(wkday, "DD/MM/YYYY"))))
                    nwday = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(wkday, -1))
                    Findrng = bday

                ElseIf Me.Freq1 = "6 Monthly" Then
                    wkday = CDate(Format(DateAdd("M", 6, (CDate(Findrng))) + 1, "MM/DD/YYYY"))
                    bday = DateAdd("D", -1, ((Format(wkday, "DD/MM/YYYY"))))
                    nwday = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(wkday, -1))
                    Findrng = bday
'                    Findrng = FindRowNumber + ((CDate(bday) - CDate(Findrng)))

                ElseIf Me.Freq1 = "Yearly" Then
                    wkday = CDate(Format(DateAdd("M", 12, (CDate(Findrng))) + 1, "MM/DD/YYYY"))
                    bday = DateAdd("D", -1, ((Format(wkday, "DD/MM/YYYY"))))
                    nwday = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(wkday, -1))
                    Findrng = bday
'                    Findrng = FindRowNumber + ((CDate(bday) - CDate(Findrng)))

                End If
                i = i + 1
            End With

        Loop
    End If

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) should clear your concepts :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have had a look at the page, thanks. I am still struggling with the line "Set Daycell" the outcome of that is "15/06/2017" which is the string that I am looking for and not the cell address. Can you help?

Comment: `If Not Daycell  is nothing then Msgbox Daycell.Value`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry, i am not looking to get a message box, I want to use the cell address to populate that cell with a comment. How can I find the cell address/range using the Set Daycell line?

Comment: see the answer that i posted. you may have to refresh the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @SiddharthRout Sorry, i am not looking to get a message box, I want to use the cell address to populate that cell with a comment. How can I find the cell address/range using the Set Daycell line? – Steven Craig 1 min ago

You said you wanted the value and hence I gave that example. If you want to insert a comment in that cell then you will have to do it like this (**Untested**)

```
Dim Daycell As Range

With Range("A1:A100")
    Set Daycell = .Find(What:=Dayno, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not Daycell Is Nothing Then '<~~ Check if a match was found
       With Daycell
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Visible = False
            .Comment.Text Text:="This is a sample comment"
       End With
    End If
End With
```

Comment: This works, thanks. If I want to add 1 row to "Daycell" how would I manage this?

Comment: Well try it. I already showed you one example. You just can't ask all your questions in one post ;) You started with something and then ended up with something else.

Comment: Different Question = Different Post ;)

Comment: That was in my original post "so that I can use that address to populate adjacent cells with info. " I thought I would need to use `.Cell(Daycell).Offset (1)" ` but this is what seems to be my problem. I was wrong in thinking that my problem was on the Set line.

Comment: You need to use `Daycell.Offset()`

Comment: In the `With Daycell - End With` code that I gave you, you can interact with that cell. :)

Comment: Do you mean like this `With Daycell .Offset (1)`?  this gives me an invalid use of property. Sorry for so many questions

Comment: Gimme 15 mins. I am trying to help someone else. Brb after that

Comment: Sorry Steven it got delayed. I am trying to help someone [Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146764/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-acr) Once that is done, I will get back to you

Comment: Ok I am here. Let me know exactly what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi Sorry I was away. I have a userform that will input the detail from that form into a calendar in excel. The form allows for reoccurring items at different intervals that works as I expect. The input allows a main title which populates correctly. I would also like for further detail to be allowable which will end up as a comment on the cell the title goes into. I have 3 cells below each date so 3 possible items per day. The code you have helped with finds the date I want to use but I want the comment to be in the cell below that up to 3 places. update the code with my latest try. Thanks

Comment: Change `With Daycell` to `With Daycell.Offset(3)` in my code

Comment: Something has gone wrong and I cant even get past the findwor line. I cannot see anything that has changed so I cant test this in my code

Comment: Hi, I have managed to get it to work. Thank you for all the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
    Dim Daycell As Range
    With Range("A1:A100")
        Set Daycell = .Find(What:=Dayno, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not Daycell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox Daycell.Column
            MsgBox Daycell.Row
        End If
    End With
```

Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Comment: `LookAt:=xlValues` A typo I guess? :)